# How to use TPM for key management

Tags: tpm, key

I have read about TPM that these are the secured ways of storing cryptographic keys. I want to know how can I use it. I have an application running on a PC which has TPM. This application has hard coded symmetric key in it.AS the hard coding the keys are not recommended from security point of view , I want to store my encryption key on the TPM. How can I implement it in python.

So how can i use the security features of TPM (1.2) to securely store my key. My application is developed using python. So how can i access TMP to store my symmetric key. Please suggest.

Comment: What TPM are you talking about? Have you looked up the documentation? It sounds like you need to read some basic information about TPMs first.

Comment: @schroeder I am talking about Trusted Platform module installed in desktop computers. The TPM specification version is 1.2. I have gone through some blogs on internet about TPM

Comment: TPM is a *product type*. There are many. And you want one that has a Python library. Your question is a little like: "how do I use a vehicle?" Are you talking about a bike? a car? a boat? First, look for TPMs that meet your basic need, then read about that one.

Comment: @schroeder: I think you're mixing up TPMs with HSMs? I've _only_ ever seen the term "TPM" to mean the specific product defined by the TCG group (as opposed to HSMs). There may be many, but from the software side they all follow the same TCG spec and have the same features and APIs – any TPM of version 1.2 is the same as any other TPM of version 1.2, so saying "find one that meets your needs" doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @user1686 I thank you for double-checking to make sure everyone is on the same page.  But there are different implementations of TPMs (including software TPM emulators). What the OP appears to be asking is how to access the specific TPM on their specific machine using Python. For that, more info is required. And it tends to be a simple documentation look-up once you have that info. So my question to the OP is apt: "what TPM are you talking about?"

Comment: @schroeder  First of all I am a newbie about TPM. I have read that TPM may be used for Disk encryption using Bitlocker and also it can be used to store encryption keys securily. My interest was more on storing encryption keys. So how TPM may be used to store encryption keys. Whether it is done at the API level using some programming language or by some other means. Thats whys i had requested to show me direction or refer any relevant documents.

Comment: And I have mentioned that you still need to do some basic reading. And you have still not specified which TPM. https://www.google.com/search?q=store+keys+in+tpm